# Add dependency to git project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I am not able to find an answer to this question: How is it possible to make an project dependend on a git project in Eclipse? I am only able to find answers on this topic for maven projects or jar files.
Specifically, i am trying to make my project dependent on [this git project](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook). I was able to import it Eclipse, the src folder and everything inside it is shown correctly. 
But i am not able to add it as dependency to my project, simply because Eclipse does not show the project in its dialogs. How is one supposed to add such projects?

Comment: I don't think git handles dependencies. Have you checked here [Project Dependencies - Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Project_Dependencies)?

Comment: So it is impossible to add git projects directly?

Comment: What do you mean by impossible? Git is a distributed version control system not a dependency manager. People use tools like npm to manage dependencies.